# How to get data from fields, not entire document. Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from fields on my firebase firestore, but not the whole document. 
[Fields that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWP7.png)

Here is my code that get the whole document.

```
db.collection("Reminder").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                            dbReminder p = d.toObject(dbReminder.class);
                            p.setId(d.getId());
                            remtasklist.add(p);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            });
```

Thanks in advance.
Edit: I updated with the collection pic.
[Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSWP7.png)

Comment: Please show you firebase collection a bit more in that screenshot

Comment: There is no API to get only a specific field.  You must read the entire document to get any field in that document.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath updated with a pic now

Comment: T@DougStevenson This is an android related question, not a swift one., how can it be a duplicate.

Comment: You need to query the collection and get the specific user you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get specific fields from the documentSnapshot.

```
 String location = documentSnapshot.getString("inLocation");
 String time = documentSnapshot.getString("time");//assuming time here is string
 String title = documentSnapshot.getString("title");
```

Comment: If you don't want to use loops, you have to write your query better `db.collection("Reminder").document("mydocumenthere");`. This way, you can directly get the fields from the document snapshot.

Comment: ok thanks it works for now, thank you again